# Removing duplicates where the relationship is only clear by comparing lines (relative reference in R)

Tags: r

**The situation:** I have some data about contracts, and how many acres are covered by a contract in a given year. The contracts I am dealing with have an obnoxious naming convention which is contract renewals have the same name with 'a', 'b', 'c', etc appended after the number.

Because contracts can be renewed at any time, calculating the acreage in a given year means that there is double-counting when the renewal begins. Some example data might help to explain:

```
example <- data.frame(contract = c('c300a', 'c300b'),
                      true_contract = c('c300', 'c300'),
                      acres_2007 = c(100, 0),
                      acres_2008 = c(100, 100),
                      acres_2009 = c(0, 100)
)
print(example)

  contract true_contract acres_2007 acres_2008 acres_2009
1    c300a          c300        100        100          0
2    c300b          c300          0        100        100
```

As you can see, if the transition from `300a` to `300b` happened on (for example) May 20, 2008, then there is double-counting in 2008. Those 100 acres are the same piece of land. I would like a way to remove one of the 100s - it doesn't matter which, since both contracts are functionally "the same".

I can tell the problem by looking at it, but am completely puzzled about how I would address the issue using `R`. In fact, I have always been at a loss about how to deal with data issues where the relationship is only clear from looking at lines that are next to each other. This is a very Excel-style mindset (relative reference) but I am not good at Excel/VBA. In addition, I come up against problems like this often enough that figuring out how to map this problem to R solutions would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general solution that applies a rule to all contracts in all years. The rule I used was "For each contract-year with more than one contract, keep the largest one, and if more than one at that size, keep the later one."

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

example %>%
  # Split contract name into two, putting last letter/digit into new column
  separate(contract, c("contract", "renewal_ltr"), sep = -1) %>%

  # Gather into long form to make counting easier
  gather(year_col, acres, -c(contract:true_contract)) %>%

  # Optional: extract year from year_col; dropped below but might be of use.
  mutate(year = readr::parse_number(year_col)) %>%

  # For contracts with more than one value in a year, keep the larger one, 
  #   or if tied, keep the later one
  group_by(contract, year_col) %>%
  arrange(year, desc(acres), desc(renewal_ltr)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%   # Keep top row per group
  ungroup() %>%

  # Optional: spread back
  select(-year) %>%
  spread(year_col, acres, fill = 0)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  contract renewal_ltr true_contract acres_2007 acres_2008 acres_2009
  <chr>    <chr>       <fct>              <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 c300     a           c300                 100          0          0
2 c300     b           c300                   0        100        100
```

Comment: This was exactly the ticket, thank you. Also thanks for finally convincing me the need to learn the tidyverse; I've been holding out but I can tell I'm falling way behind now.

Comment: Oh, only other comment is that I needed to also use `library(readr)` to get `parse_number` to work; I didn't want to edit your answer though. It could be this was also an issue only I was having because of ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

If I undestood correctly you want to remove one of the duplicated 100 from the second column. This keeps the first value in the acres_2008 column and replace the other with 0

```
example$acres_2008 <- ave(
  example$acres_2008, 
  example$true_contract, 
  FUN = function(a) replace(a, duplicated(a), 0)
)
```

The result with your example is:

[image]